# peculiar OutOfMemory exception

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

after big struggle i wrote "game engine" and i found very strange bug.
when you move your form around you get OutOfMemory exception (application jumps from needing 24 MB to over 6 GB of ram in less than 5 seconds) but that not isn't the wierdest thing. this appears ONLY when you move form up, in any other direction nothing will happen. here is piece of code that i wrote that works similary as my application although this crashes instantly after moving form up

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication10
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Graphics h;
    Bitmap bmp;
    System.Threading.Thread WTF;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void LOL()
    {

        bmp = new Bitmap(500, 500);
        Graphics WHAAAAT = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        while (true)
        {

            WHAAAAT.FillEllipse(Brushes.Black, 50, 50, 50, 50);
            h.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 0);

        }
    }
    private void WOOT(Graphics g)
    {
        h = g;
        WTF = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(LOL));
        WTF.Start();
    }

    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics d = panel1.CreateGraphics();
        d.FillEllipse(Brushes.Black, 50, 50, 50, 50);
        WOOT(d);
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        WTF.Abort();
    }
}
```

}

Form border style is set to singleFixed. any idea why this thing happens?
in my case it throws other exception caused by enormous RAM usage but it also appears only when you move form up

Comment: Have you profiled it?

Comment: having a variable named WTF is the c# backdoor for nasal demons, that's why weird things are happening :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a bug, it is the result of your excessive thread creation:

```
private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics d = panel1.CreateGraphics();
    d.FillEllipse(Brushes.Black, 50, 50, 50, 50);
    WOOT(d);
}
```

Every time the panel is redrawn (which is normally done when invalidated due to window movement), you create a new thread (calling `WOOT`, creative name by the way). However, this thread runs forever (see `LOL`, also a creative name)

So, as soon as you start moving your form and parts of that panel get invalidated (e.g. when they are covered by something else or off-screen), as soon as they get displayed again, the `Paint` event is raised.

And then, you create a new thread, let it run forever, and continue moving the form, creating a new thread, and so on...

So what you should do, is to create a method (suggestion: call it `ROFL`, `YOLO` or `SWAG`) that destroys the thread prior to spawning a new one.

Comment: thats explains everything. Also why does it repaint only when you move form up?

Comment: It repaints always a part of your panel is covered and has to be repainted again when that part is exposed to the viewer again.